# How to insert a sum from a table in another table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables

```
Categories:        Materials:
Id|Name          Id|Name|IdCateg
1 |C1            1 |N1  |1
2 |C2            
3 |C3

Materials:
Id|Name|IdCateg
1 |N1  |1
2 |N2  |1
3 |N3  |2
4 |N4  |2
5 |N5  |3
6 |N6  |3


Acquisitions:
Id|IdMat|Amount
1 |  1  | 10
2 |  1  | 5 
3 |  1  | 30
4 |  2  | 23
5 |  2  | 10
```

SO i want in table STOCK the sum of amounts from table Aquisitions where IdMat is the same like this

```
STOCK:
Id|IdMat|Amount
1 |  1  |  45
2 |  2  |  33
```

HOW CAN i DO this?

I have tried to do this but it update it with the same value on every id:

```
update STOCK
set Amount=
    (
        select sum(a.Amount) 
        from AQUISITIONS a  JOIN STOCK s
        ON s.IdMat=a.IdMat
        WHERE(s.IdMat=1)
    ) 
where exists 
    (
        select 1 
       from AQUISITIONS a  JOIN STOCK s
        ON s.IdMat=a.IdMat
    )
```

Comment: Create a view instead. Will alwasy be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is just getting the sum for `idMat = 1`, and setting the amount in all stocks to that same amount. To do it right, the subquery should be correlated to the main table, not use a join inside the subquery.

But an easier way is to write a grouped subquery and then just join that to the table you want to update.

```
UPDATE STOCK AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT idMat, SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM Aquisitions
    GROUP BY idMat
) AS a ON s.idMat = a.idMat
SET s.Amount = a.total
```